# Why is Python's Decimal precision not related to floating point precision?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

#### Background

In Python's `decimal` module, `getcontext`, through the `prec` attribute, sets the precision for the `Decimal` objects one constructs. I find it rather strange that the term "precision" is used, since it leads to the assumption as to how `decimal` handles floating point numbers that could exceed such precision on their decimal part (i.e., the fraction/non-integer part).

However, in the `decimal` module, "precision" seems to refer to the actual count of digits in a `Decimal` object:

```
In [1]: from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
In [2]: l = [Decimal('0.1234567890123456789'),
             Decimal('1.1234567890123456789'),
             Decimal('20.1234567890123456789'),
             Decimal('300.1234567890123456789'),
             Decimal('-4000.1234567890123456789')]

In [3]: [+e for e in l]
Out[3]:
[Decimal('0.1234567890123456789'),
 Decimal('1.1234567890123456789'),
 Decimal('20.1234567890123456789'),
 Decimal('300.1234567890123456789'),
 Decimal('-4000.1234567890123456789')]

In [4]: c = getcontext()
   ...: c.prec = 5 # Spicing things up
   ...: [+e for e in l] # Infix + operator reconstructs objects with current precision
Out[4]:
[Decimal('0.12346'),
 Decimal('1.1235'),
 Decimal('20.123'),
 Decimal('300.12'),
 Decimal('-4000.1')]

In [5]: c.prec = 15
   ...: [+e for e in l]
Out[5]:
[Decimal('0.123456789012346'),
 Decimal('1.12345678901235'),
 Decimal('20.1234567890123'),
 Decimal('300.123456789012'),
 Decimal('-4000.12345678901')]

In [6]: c.prec = 60
   ...: [+e for e in l] # Precision larger than original Decimals recreates the objects
Out[6]:
[Decimal('0.1234567890123456789'),
 Decimal('1.1234567890123456789'),
 Decimal('20.1234567890123456789'),
 Decimal('300.1234567890123456789'),
 Decimal('-4000.1234567890123456789')]
```

With the exception of Decimals between `-1` and `1`, which ignore the leading zero as a digit, we see that precision on the floating part of the number varies according to its magnitude.

The Standard Library [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) actually hints that the precision is not the number of floating points, but rather overall digits (although it never explicitly *tells* readers about this caveat):

> Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a user alterable precision (defaulting to 28 **places**) which can be as large as needed for a given problem

But even in this passage, one could easily interpret as **"28 *[decimal]* places"**.

---

#### My point

I have a few issues with the implementation of `getcontext.prec` in the `decimal` module referring to "count of digits".

1. **On a technical nature:** why the leading zero does not count as with other Decimals? (I'd suppose it has something to do with scientific notation, but I'd like clarification on the matter)
2. **On a semantic nature:** why would the developers of the Standard Library refer to "precision" as digit counting and not floating point precision, as we often do both inside (e.g., specifying the `round` function) and outside computing (e.g., "I want answers with a 5-point precision")? To me the term "precision" is misleading in the `decimal` module, as it is explicitly mentioned early in the documentation:

   > Decimal “is based on a floating-point model which was designed with people in mind, and necessarily has a paramount guiding principle – computers must provide an arithmetic that works in the same way as the arithmetic that people learn at school.”
3. **On a practical level:** how would I have to work if my implementation requires the use of Decimals, but I need to set precision in regards to the floating part of a number, which could vary from `1` to `1,000,000,000` and beyond as its integer part? Obviously the most hands-on approach is to simply use `round` to set precision, but it seems cumbersome, especially when dealing with multiple numbers that are not necessarily contained in sequences, which could lead to unnecessary code repetition.

Comment: This is the standard meaning of "precision" in a floating-point context. For example, [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic): "the number 152,853.5047, which has ten decimal digits of precision ..."; from the IEEE 754 "definitions" section 2.1: "The maximum number p of significant digits that can be represented in a format, or the number
of digits to which a result is rounded.". From the handbook of floating-point arithmetic (Muller et al), p.13: "roughly speaking, [the precision] p is the number of significant digits of the representation".

Comment: So Python's Decimal precision *is* exactly the floating-point precision, as the term is commonly understood.